# Unable to display database on Fullcalendar

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I'm currently trying to create a JSON feed for FullCalendar. I currently have a working example, However the output doesn't get my database into the calendar. Anyone have any ideas? I've been stuck on this now..

In my codes:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src='js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
  <script src='js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js'></script>
  <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
  <script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,

        events : "test1.php",
    eventClick: function(event) {
            // opens events in a popup window
            window.open(event.url, '', 'width=700,height=600');
            return false;
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) {
                $('#loading').show();
            }else{
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        }   

    });

});

   </script>
    <style>

body {
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    }

#calendar {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

   </style>
   </head>
    <body>
   <div id='calendar'></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Code for test1.php

```
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','abc123');
 if (!$link) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
 mysql_select_db('trainingcourse');

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_course ");

 Initializes a container array for all of the calendar events
 $jsonArray = array();

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
   $eventtest = $row['courseid'];
   $startdate = $row['startdate'];
   $starttime = $row['starttime'];
     $enddate = $row['enddate'];
     $endtime = $row['endtime'];

    // Stores each database record to an array
    $buildjson = array('courseid' => "$eventtest", 'startdate' => "$startdate", 'enddate' => "$enddate", 'allday' => false);

    // Adds each array into the container array
    array_push($jsonArray, $buildjson);
      }
    // Output the json formatted data so that the jQuery call can read it
    echo json_encode($jsonArray);
       ?>
```

It is unable to display on Calendar.

I am really appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
<?php 
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','abc123');
 if (!$link) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
 mysql_select_db('trainingcourse',$link);

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_course ");


  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
   $eventtest = $row['courseid'];
   $startdate = $row['startdate'];
   $starttime = $row['starttime'];
     $enddate = $row['enddate'];
     $endtime = $row['endtime'];

    // Stores each database record to an array
    $buildjson[] = array(
                         'courseid'  => $eventtest, 
                         'startdate' => $startdate, 
                         'enddate'   => $enddate, 
                         'allday'    => false
                         );


  }
    // Output the json formatted data so that the jQuery call can read it
    echo json_encode($buildjson);
       ?><br>
```

Hope it works. Please also try to print the results **print_r($buildjson);**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I tried it and same as before. It is unable to display database on calendar.

Comment: Could you check what php version you are using? json_encode() works only on PHP 5.3.0 and above. This code works for me.

Comment: I checked the version is PHP 5.1.6. Basically, I do not know what wrong is with my code. Please help!!

Comment: ok json will not work actually on lower version of php can you upgrade to 5.3 or greater?

Comment: you can add a function that display a json format if your are on a lower version of php

Comment: I have upgraded to PHP 5.3.3 now. I tried it again. However, it is also unable to display database on Calendar.-

Comment: can you give to me the result of the echo json_encode($buildjson);

Comment: The is coming up nothing. your can try http://113.28.30.89/test/fullcalendar/test1.php

Comment: or you can browse http://113.28.30.89/test/fullcalendar/ . That is unable to show up the php database on.

Comment: When I upgraded to PHP version 5.3.3 the php connection is coming up HTTP 500 Internet Server. Please help!!-

Comment: can you add ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); on the top of test1.php?

Comment: Mysql is dead. It is unable to connect database. I need to set up it again. It may be finished by next day. I will install virtual server (XAMPP) on my computer as well.

Comment: Mysql is up now. the database connection is working. test1.php shows up the database on the internet. However, database does not show up on calendar. Please help..

Comment: test1.php have been changed. you can browse 113.28.30.89/test/fullcalendar/test1.php. data is showing up on the screen. However, 113.28.30.89/test/fullcalendar/index.php the data does not show up on screen.Please help!!

Comment: hahaha. i found out the issue check out your test1.php json format. Please change courseid to title, startdate to start and enddate to end. it works. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, this is same issue as before.

Comment: i tested your code on your server and it works for me. i just change "courseid" to "title", "startdate" to "start" and "enddate" to "end" on your json format. hope you get it.

Comment: change your code to $buildjson = array('title' => $eventtest, 'start' => $startdate." ".$starttime , 'end' => $enddate." ".$endtime, 'allday' => false);

Comment: The results of test1.php must be this [{"title":"NETTS001","start":"2013-09-30 09:00:00","end":"2013-10-18 18:00:00","allday":false},{"title":"YMMD01","start":"2013-09-02 09:00:00","end":"2013-09-02 17:00:00","allday":false},{"title":"YMMPCDVAS20131015","start":"2013-10-13 09:00:00","end":"2013-10-28 18:30:00","allday":false},{"title":"NETTSNOWTV20131015","start":"2013-10-28 09:00:00","end":"2013-11-08 18:00:00","allday":false}]

Comment: I separated 2 fields for start date and time. It shall arrange course time table easily. It called startdate, starttime, enddate and endtime.

Comment: Is it able to use 2 different fields for Start Date and Start Time for Calendar. However, when I upgraded to PHP 5.3.3, login session is unable to access login pager. Please Help!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me

on your PHP code:
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($jsonArray);

on you html code:
add this option to you calendar:
        eventSources: [

```
            // your event source
            {
                url: 'url/of/your/jsonphp',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    custom_param1: 'something',
                    custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                },
                color: '#dadada',
                textColor: '#000000'
            }
```

Comment: Hey, I am not sure where the location "header('Content-Type: application/json');" is. index.php or test1.php?? and also where the event source is on? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: the header('Content-Type: application/json') should be called before you ouput the JSON data.it should be on your test1.php. the eventSources should be on your index.php during initialization of calendar

Comment: i tried it again. However, it is unable to show up on screen again.